# $\phi(u, v) = (2u-v, 3u+2v) =: (x, y)$, compute: $ \phi^*(−ydx + 2xdy)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, pullback

Let $ \phi : R^2 → R^2$ be the differentiable application defined by $\phi(u, v) = (2u-v, 3u+2v) =: (x, y) $.
Compute:

$$\phi^*(−ydx + 2xdy). $$

What I thought:

\begin{align}
(\phi^*w)(x)&=(\phi^*(−ydx + 2xdy))(x)\\
&=(\phi^*(−(3u+2v)d(2u-v) + 2(2u-v)d(3u+2v)))(x)\\
&=−(3u+2v)d(2u-v) + 2(2u-v)d(3u+2v)
\end{align}

I don't know if it can be right and I wouldn't know how to proceed...

Comment: After you change to $(u, v)$ the $\phi^*$ should be gone.

Comment: Could you make it clear what you mean by $\phi^\ast$?

Comment: @ArcticChar so if I remove the $\phi^*$ is that right?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I think is a pull-bach $(\phi^*w)$ where $w$ is $(-ydx + 2xdy)$